# Error Parsing Gemfile; Cannot Deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Having a hard time pushing to heroku. Im using the most current version of rails and ruby. Each time I try to upload to heroku I get this message. 
[code]
$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of          known hosts.
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 15.99 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 69 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:88:in `block in           ruby_version': There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue        (LanguagePack::Helpers::BundlerWrapper::GemfileParseError)
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in        instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in     `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:76:in      `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:80:in   `ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:180:in `block in ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in     instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in  `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:173:in `ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:259:in `block in install_ruby'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in   instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument' 
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:258:in `install_ruby'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `block in compile'  
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in  instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:83:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in   instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument' 
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in  instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:124:in `log'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:14:in `block in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `call'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument' 
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:10:in `<main>'

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-8467.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-8467.git'
 Richards-MacBook-Pro-2:hockeyapp richardlane$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.3
[/code]
```

and here is my gemfile:

```
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6' 

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record



group :production do

    gem 'pg'

end



group :development do

    gem 'sqlite3'

end





# Use SCSS for stylesheets

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for Javascript assets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby



# Use jquery as the Javascript library

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:            https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc



# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read      more: https://github.com/rails/spring

gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

[/code]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the following code in your gemfile

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
ruby "2.1.1"
```

you can follow these step

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 1):

For **Rails '4.1.6'** version, the required **Ruby** version must be greater than or equals to (**>=**) **1.9.3**.

So add any of the ruby versions like 1.9.3p2, 1.9.3-p547, 2.0.0-p576, 2.1.1 etc;

Comment: I am using ruby 2.1.3p242

Comment: I think the problem is that I may be using 2.1.3 on my computer but I need to install the same version on Heroku? I didn't realize that I had to install it on both. I'm going to give it another shot tonight by following these instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is experiencing API issues https://status.heroku.com/ https://status.heroku.com/incidents/673 and has temporary disabled API access.

This may be part of the issue as currently apps cannot be deployed, fetched or updated either through the CLI or Heroku Dashboard.