# failed to push some refs to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I got an error when "git push heroku master"

the same error using "git push heroku master -f"

The error:

```
Counting objects: 43015, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14389/14389), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43015/43015), 18.52 MiB | 594.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 43015 (delta 26894), reused 42969 (delta 26863)
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: 
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: sh: 1: Gemfile: not found
remote: sh: 1: branch: not found
remote: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
remote:     Unknown command recaptcha
remote:  !
remote:  !     There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
remote:  !     
remote:  !     [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: The `branch` option     for `gem 'recaptcha'` is not allowed. Only gems with a git source can specify a branch. Bundler cannot continue.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     #  from /tmp/build_05d951a3e30701bcecb25fd61ce3f179/Gemfile:46
remote:  !     #  -------------------------------------------
remote:  !     #  gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
remote:  !     >  gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3'
remote:  !     #
remote:  !     #  -------------------------------------------
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to arcane-retreat-58893.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-retreat-58893.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arcane-retreat-58893.git'
```

first do a "git pull" to merge, then push command didn't work for me,either.

Comment: The log tells you everything. If not clear, contact with the repository owner. It has nothing to do with `git pull`. It's declined by a remote hook.

Answer (score 0):

```
There was an error parsing your Gemfile
```

As illustrated by this [2014 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26281559/6309), heroku has always has pre-receive hook ([server side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks)) for testing/checking per-requisites.
Starting with the [Ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions) or other criteria.